# Loading an image into a background in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, background-image

I'm wondering how to successfully add a background image view into a table view with static cells. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

UITableView has a background view that you can use for this purpose. You can access this view like so:

```
yourTableView.backgroundView
```

So you can add your image to this view.

```
if let tableView = self.view as? UITableView {
        let image = UIImage(named: "myxcassetsimage")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        tableView.backgroundView = imageView
    }
```

this snipped assumes you have a Table View Controller setup on your storyboard. So it checks if your self.view is a UITableView and adds an image from your asset catalogue to the background view.

please note that the static cells you're talking about have to have clear/transparent background, otherwise you won't see the image behind the cells.

Comment: `UITableViewController` has a `tableView` property, you don't need to check if `self.view` is `UITableView`.

Comment: One other thing to take note as that if you have a lot of cells, having clear or transparent cells are not going to be the best thing ever. It's much better to have opaque cells whenever possible.

Comment: This solution is working for me, but I found out, that the properties for opaque, bgcolor... in xcode 8 aren't accepted for older builds (iOS 9 for example). I don't know, if I missed something, but I built a solution, referencing the tableviewcells as outlets to the code and made them opaque, the backgroundcolor clear and the backgroundview nil. Maybe this will help someone else :)